# MjpegInputStream manually set fps

Tags: android, video, stream, mjpeg

I am using MjpegView and MjpegInputStream. I am receiving video stream from ip camera. I would like to manually set fps for saving transmision on mobile devices. In main loop I added thread.sleep witch sleeps thread for some time to achive manually set fps level. It works, but when I set x<30 fps it seems that stream buffors frames and video slows down and get delayed. How can I skip some frames and always get last frame received from input stream?